# Increasing number of duplicates on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Personally, I enjoy all the variety of topics covered by the Stack Exchange network. I have been more active on Stack Overflow though. Stack Overflow has helped me immensely to improve my knowledge, especially the R language.

I have started getting a feeling that the number of new questions on Stack Overflow has reduced drastically. Most of the questions which we get are duplicates of some other question which was already asked and answered in the past. The only job most of us do is to find a right duplicate of that question and mark it.

Although, the number of question per day posted on Stack Overflow might not have reduced but number of questions which are not duplicates looks reduced and I believe, this is going to continue further.

I do not have any statistics to prove that and it is based only on what I have observed in past couple of months in the R tag. Is this problem real? If yes, what is way this can be handled ?

Comment: Is that really a problem? Shouldn't this be a natural evolution?

Comment: I think there have been discussions and/or feature requests to improve the questions suggested when your start writing a new post but you also have to get users to pay attention to what's suggested.

Comment: It's all Microsoft's fault. You can only do so much with CSS (which limits the number of possible "new" questions) while also trying to make sure IE and Edge don't choke to death... /s

Comment: Wait until R updates its language with new features, or new 3rd-party library, etc and expect whole new questions. But to answer your question, that's natural since good questions were already posted, leaving with duplicate only.

Comment: This will always be the case with programming sites. The vast majority of questions regarding older programming languages had already been answered _long before_ SO even existed. People keep asking the same questions over and over, as new people learn those languages.

Comment: Hasn't this issue been raised before?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I like the irony here.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra: This process cannot be automated. Many times, the questions that share a common answer have almost nothing in common. This is in part, because users fail to properly abstract their problem, but also in part, because users ask about their solutions, rather than their problems.

Comment: *"The only job most of us do is to find a right duplicate of that question and mark it."* Funny, I've observed quite the opposite, at least in the JavaScript tag. There are a number of high-rep users who answer almost every question, duplicate or not.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well, there are always users who are on SO just for the rep. Users who prefer to answer the question instead of investing their time in finding the duplicates. (and maybe this is the reason why they are high-rep ? ;-) )

Comment: I've started about 1.5 yrs ago actively taking part in SO, so my experience is limited. However, my gut feeling is the same as Ronak's that there is an increase in badly researched, ill-posed, and duplicated questions. Now, that this Q has been closed as dupe itself it appears that this might not be an actual "trend". So, my gut feeling might be wrong. I wonder if there are any statistics to measure this?

Answer (score -26):

I think overzealous mods marking *everything* as a duplicate of some vaguely-related-at-best-but-certainly-not-similar-enough-to-actually-help-you question from literally a decade ago is BY FAR the greater problem.

It's completely ridiculous and it's making the climate here incredibly hostile. I don't think we've reached 4chan levels, certainly, but it's more hostile here than on Reddit.

(Edit: it doesn't matter if it actually is a duplicate or not, people. Sending me to a 10-year-old answer by a person who may not even still be a member, from which I cannot ask follow-ups, is still hostile and ridiculous)

Comment: I believe the far greater problem is text posted as an answer, that doesn't even attempt to answer a question.

Comment: Can you show some examples of "aguely-related-at-best-but-certainly-not-similar-enough-to-actually-help-you" duplicate closings? Do you have any hard evidence (beyond your gut feeling) that that problem is bigger than duplicate questions? Because my gut feeling is exactly the opposite, and I've come across very few really bad duplicate closings (compared to other problems).

Comment: @IInspectable Way to prove my point about a hostile climate. He asked if the question was real and I answered no. Answers you don't like are still answers.

Comment: @Pekka웃 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776603/php-form-post-to-toggle-a-variable-only-working-in-one-direction

Comment: I fail to see, where in your 'answer' you answered with *"No"*. Or even addressed the question. I guess this really only proves, that users of this site that contribute low-quality content are more likely to perceive the climate as hostile, than those users, that provide high-quality contributions.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, you've already spoken English too fluently for me to believe that you couldn't interpret my answer as a "no." And sorry, trying to get me to lash at you at you by labeling me "low quality content" only proves my point about the hostile environment. Trolling fail.

Comment: @LeeSaxon This is an exact duplicate. You don't need to ask for follow up, SO is not a forum, it's a repository of knowledge for professional and enthousiasts with the form of Question and Answers. What show your question is that you lack the very basics you can find in every tutorial on the net. I can tell because I learned PHP solo with a tutorial and what you try to do, I learned it myself in the tutorial.

Comment: @Lee agreed, that was not a *perfect* duplicate closing in that the dupe doesn't explain what you did wrong *specifically* - but  it arguably still gives you what you need in the top voted answer. If a question demonstrates lack of understanding of a basic concept, it is perfectly reasonable to link to a question that explains the basic concept, rather than explain the same thing for the 10,000th time - after all the site gets 12,000+ new questions every day. This is an edge case, though, and it would certainly have been nice to accompany the closing with a helpful comment.

Comment: @Walfrat My issue had nothing to do with sessions. At all. I overlooked that I hadn't put the initial declaration in a conditional, so it was overriding the POST conditional. Nothing to do with sessions.

Comment: To comment on your last edit: There is no 10-year-old content on a site that has only [existed for 8 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow). At any rate, this question is asking, whether *problem x* is real, and your contribution is, that the climate is hostile. Besides, the overwhelming majority of duplicates aren't closed by moderators. This site is user-moderated to a large degree. I suggest you revisit the [tour].

Comment: `My issue had nothing to do with sessions. At all.`  yeah, you have a point there. "Use sessions instead" may be a meta answer to what you should be doing next but it didn't exactly address the problem you had. Fair. Closings can go wrong and personally, I would have commented instead (as I did a couple minutes ago). I still don't see a rampant problem with imperfect or incorrect closings in general and I put it to you you are likely to see the issue as more widespread than it actually is because you were directly affected by an instance of it. A human reaction that we all have.

Comment: @Pekka웃 fair enough that may be true. I've run across this a few times searching through old questions but confirmation bias is a rough mistress

Comment: @IInspectable I picked a generic number to illustrate my point. But you knew that.

Comment: That point is **completely** moot. Whether a solution to a problem is *x* years old does not make that solution any less applicable. It is one of the outstanding features of SO to persist information. I have come **very** rare occasions, where an old solution to a problem was so outdated, that it almost didn't apply anymore. In the grand majority of cases, old answers to old problems are still relevant.

Comment: @LeeSaxon And in what a 8y old answer can't be used anymore ? As I said, SO is not a forum, it is not made for you to put a follow up with those that have answered, whatever the age of the answer. If an answer brings you a new question, you can ask for it, after searching if it wasn't been answered already using google.

Comment: This circlejerk legacy of that infamous post [The decline of Stack Overflow](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) has lived on long enough. It is not "hostile" to have your non-mcve question closed as a duplicate. It is "hostile" to not even take the effort to reduce your code to the minimum example necessary to reproduce your issue, along with a proper explanation of what you expect, what you observe and what you tried to fix the differences between those two. We have a [very small page explaining how to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This definitely does not answer my question. In fact this is a new question in itself.

Comment: The title of this post "Increasing number of duplicates on Stack Overflow [duplicate]" is like inception: wheels within wheels. Love it. I myself have asked many questions that could be considered duplicates (many of which were helpfully answered by Ronak) simply because I didn't have the vernacular to ask the question properly or the skills to search for the answer properly. That being said I have never experienced hostility here.